# Eclipse issue: unit tests triggered when I debug but not when I run

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, spring-kafka-test

Goal: I want to "unit" test kafka producer sending messages to a kafka hosted in a docker container. In other words, it must connect to external kafka other than the common used for unit test named Embedded Kafka.

I can successfully reach my kafka docker container from command line:

```
C:\tools\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 192.168.99.100:9092 --topic test
>123 testing
>Deseja finalizar o arquivo em lotes (S/N)? S

C:\tools\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server 192.168.99.100:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
test
a
123 testing
```

I also had success when I debug my unit test. I have checked and both run and debug configuration are the same.

Nevertheless, when I run my junit test I don't see any tentative to connect to same kafka broker. Here is the config. You may note I tried add in all places I could imagine the address might be read from

"unit test" (discuss if it is unit or integrated is beyond this question)

src/test/java

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest
class KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Producer p;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", "192.168.99.100:9092");
    }

    @Test
    public void testReceive() throws Exception {
        p.send("test", "Messagem demonstrativa assincrona");
    }

}
```

src/test/resources/application.properties

```
kafka.brokers= 192.168.99.100:9092
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers= 192.168.99.100:9092
```

kafka producer config (same used for running the application, i.e. without tests purposes)

src/main/java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducerConfig.class);

    @Value("${kafka.brokers}")
    private String servers;
    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("KafkaMsgExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

}
```

producer (same used for production cases)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Async
    public void send(String topic, String message) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

            //Call Back de sucesso de postagem da mensagem no tópico
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final SendResult<String, String> message) {
                LOGGER.info("sent message= " + message + " with offset= " + message.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            }

            //Call Back de fracasso de postagem da mensagem no tópico 
            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
                LOGGER.error("unable to send message= " + message, throwable);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logs while running junit test

```
18:56:24.681 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
18:56:24.696 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
18:56:24.719 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
18:56:24.731 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
18:56:24.735 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/arquiteturareferencia/kafkaassyncsend/KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
18:56:24.736 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/arquiteturareferencia/kafkaassyncsend/KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
18:56:24.736 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:56:24.737 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]: KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:56:24.770 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]
18:56:24.827 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\WSs\pockafka\kafka-assync-send\target\classes\com\arquiteturareferencia\kafkaassyncsend\KafkaAssyncSendApplication.class]
18:56:24.828 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplication for test class com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests
18:56:24.925 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests]: using defaults.
18:56:24.926 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
18:56:24.934 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
18:56:24.940 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@495fac5f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@76012793, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@635572a7, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@79d94571, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@4dd02341, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@3212a8d7, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@7a1a3478, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@495b0487, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@55dfcc6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@222eb8aa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@93cf163, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@1852a3ff]
18:56:24.944 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@79351f41 testClass = KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1c32386d testClass = KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@790da477, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5fb759d6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1a4927d6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6a4f1a55], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [true] with mode [AFTER_CLASS].
18:56:24.955 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@79351f41 testClass = KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests, testInstance = com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests@1477089c, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1c32386d testClass = KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.KafkaAssyncSendApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@790da477, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5fb759d6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1a4927d6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6a4f1a55], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]].
18:56:24.981 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-02 18:56:25.258  INFO 18524 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : Starting KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests on SPANOT149 with PID 18524 (started by Cast in C:\WSs\pockafka\kafka-assync-send)
2020-03-02 18:56:25.260  INFO 18524 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-02 18:56:26.101  INFO 18524 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-03-02 18:56:26.112  INFO 18524 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-03-02 18:56:26.268  INFO 18524 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : Started KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests in 1.284 seconds (JVM running for 2.242)
2020-03-02 18:56:26.307  INFO 18524 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.99.100:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2020-03-02 18:56:26.666  INFO 18524 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
```

Logs while debugging unit test:

...

```
2020-03-02 19:19:56.049  INFO 16092 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.3.1
2020-03-02 19:19:56.052  INFO 16092 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
2020-03-02 19:19:56.052  INFO 16092 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1583187596046
2020-03-02 19:19:56.299  INFO 16092 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: f95SHyheSG-VrUrOY7_R1w
2020-03-02 19:19:56.338  INFO 16092 --- [ad | producer-1] c.a.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer    : sent message= SendResult [producerRecord=ProducerRecord(topic=test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=Messagem demonstrativa assincrona, timestamp=null), recordMetadata=test-0@5] with offset= 5
2020-03-02 19:20:17.569  INFO 16092 --- [ad | producer-1] c.a.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer    : sent message= SendResult [producerRecord=ProducerRecord(topic=test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=Messagem demonstrativa assincrona, timestamp=null), recordMetadata=test-0@6] with offset= 6
2020-03-02 19:20:17.572  INFO 16092 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-03-02 19:20:17.573  INFO 16092 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
```

*** added

Actually the unit test is called only when I point a breakpoint on it

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: How does it behave if you run the test outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Same problem. I tried mvn clean package test and it skipped my test as well. The funny thing is that if I try debug test from Eclipse without breackppoint it also skips my test. The only way to work is by adding a breackpoint and debug test. This drove me to think that there is some extra config for delaying until something is ready. At least there should be some info saying what is missing or some warinnign informing that X connection/object isn't available. Well it depends on Kafka but it is up and running and I can check it from command line. I added above an image working with breackpoint

Comment: Does this info give you a clue: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ kafka-assync-send ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration ?